# Expected string or buffer using Mega module command

Tags: python, error-handling

I get the following error when I do `mega.login(email,password)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mega\mega.py", line 26, in login
    instance.login_user(email, password)
  File "mega\mega.py", line 32, in login_user
    resp = self.api_request({'a': 'us', 'user': email, 'uh': uh})
  File "mega\mega.py", line 87, in api_request
    json_resp = json.loads(req.text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Note the file req.text is not mine, but I think its related to mega or json module. Also, I grabbbed the mega module from GitHub https://github.com/richardasaurus/mega.py
Thanks for helping me :-)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the value is not a string, such as `None`.

In your case this means `email` or `password` is `None`.

Example:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: But I did mega.login(myemail,mypassword) so I don't see what that could be None!

Comment: Please.
Your answer was maybe correct, but it does not correct the situation. When I do `mega.login(email,password)` where I fill both email and password by mine, it respond with that error. So I cannot connect to my account.